# joining column data with a delimiter and row data with other delimiter using a query formula

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[Here is the sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RSDYqjG0aVagBhE7nRDnnTUIQy0765RtWa1KvTKhkTo/copy)

I have a data

[image]

I have a query formula

```
=query(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(H1:H5<>"","Col" & MATCH(G1:G5,'VIEW_WhatsppFormat Sheet'!1:1,0) & " = '" & split(H1:H5, ",",false,true) & "'","true = true")))
```

The output of query is

[image]

I need to reframe the output result as

(true = true    OR true = true  OR true = true) AND (Col8 = 'Not Reachable' OR Col8 = 'Lost'    OR Col8 = ' Call Back Later') AND (Col9 = 'Anelio'  OR Col9 = 'The Baya Junction'   Col9 = '') AND so on

This means each column needs to be combined with OR and all rows to be combined with AND. I could have used hard coded formula but the number of columns are dynamic

How do I combine the data in this fashion?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
=arrayformula(regexreplace(substitute("("&textjoin(" OR ",1,{A11:D15,flatten(split(rept(char(9999)&" ",counta(A11:A15))," "))})&")"," OR "&char(9999)&" OR ",") AND ("),"\ OR\ "&char(9999)&"\)$","\)"))
```

Adjust the range `A11:D15` accordingly.

[image]

This works better with a range:

```
=arrayformula(regexreplace(substitute("("&textjoin(" OR ",1,if(A:A<>"",{A:D,flatten(split(rept(char(9999)&" ",max(row(A:A)))," "))},))&")"," OR "&char(9999)&" OR ",") AND ("),"\ OR\ "&char(9999)&"\)$","\)"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This might be the time for [IF](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2) to work.
Try this :

```
=arrayformula(replace(textjoin("",,if(column(A1:C3)=1,") and(" & A1:C3 ," OR " & A1:C3 )) &")",1,len(") AND "),""))
```

[image]